# Redireccionar cada mensaje recibido de una conexión TCP a una petición HTTP POST

Tags: http, post, unix, telnet

Me conecto por **telnet** a una máquina que cada 10 segundos me envía unos datos en formato **XML**. ¿Cómo puedo crear al recibir cada mensaje una petición **HTTP** **POST** donde el XML recibido por telnet iría en el cuerpo de la petición?

¿Sería posible hacerlo mediante comandos o script de **unix**?

Comment: Yo buscaría "curl"

Comment: Si te he entendido, quieres reutilizar los datos que te llegan por telnet para generar tu una petición al servidor ??

Comment: ¿ Los **xml** rebidos tienen el mismo número de líneas, o pueden variar de uno a otro ? es decir, ¿ como distingues un **xml** de otro ? ¿ solo por los tags **xml** de abertura y cierre ?

Comment: ¿ Puedes des/conectar el telnet, o tiene que ser todo en la misma sesión ?

Comment: @Trauma sí, como bien dices quiero reutilizar los datos que me llegan para generar una petición, y tendría que ser todo en la misma sesión de telnet.